# How to disable routing for some routes in react-admin?

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

I want to open some xml files from my site in the path : /file/*

ex: www.mysite.com/files/myfile.xml

Bu when i try to open my file with a window.open it's redirecting to the root and don't open my file.

How can i disable the routing fot thi specific path ?

Comment: How are you serving your application ? It looks like a server issue, not a react-admin one

Comment: Hello, i already have this issue. :( When i click into the link i'm redirected to a "Not found page" whith this url : www.mysite.com/files/myfile.xmll#/ so after seeing the iis log files i didn't find any 404 http code for myFile.xml, i think it is a routing problem.